# ADSL modem + Linksys cable connections. Also intermittent connection?

Tags: networking, wrt54g, adsl2+

I have these:

1. Windows XP / Ubuntu 12.04 desktop PC
2. DSL Connection
3. Siemens SE260 ADSL2+ modem
4. Linksys WRT54G V7, firmware 7.0.0.8

I have 2 main issues.

**First**, I don't know if I've set this up (cables and settings) correctly. As far as I know, I haven't changed anything from the modem's WAN settings:
[image: Modem Wan Settings]

And for the Router:

[image: Router WAN settings]

The only thing that I don't understand is why I have to plug the modem's ethernet cable to the ethernet port (and NOT the internet port) of the router to work. I don't know if that's an issue, since most google results say the internet port should be used. So I have this setup:

PC -> Router ethernet port 2

Router's ethernet port 1 -> modem's ethernet port

Do I need to fix anything?

**Second**, I'm having intermittent connection issues for both wired and wireless connections.
After some 15-20 minutes the connection drops. Restarting the modem or the connection resolves it.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Since this is happening very quickly (15-20 minutes), my first question here would be does this happen without the wireless router in the picture - in other words, with one PC directly connected to the modem.

Comment: _The only thing that I don't understand is why I have to plug the modem's ethernet cable to the ethernet port (and NOT the internet port) of the router to work. I don't know if that's an issue, since most google results say the internet port should be used. So I have this setup:_ This is because the modem is acting as a router as well, so it's providing DHCP and NAT for the network rather than the wireless router. Nothing to worry about, but you may later wish to reconfigure the DSL modem so that it acts as just a bridge, once everything's working.

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to mention that without the router, everything's smooth. So I'm pretty sure including the router in the network causes the issue. Any thoughts on that? On your second comment, I understand now, thanks. I'll just google on what settings I need to take care of. I still need help on my dropped connections though, thanks.

Comment: If you remove the router and have no issues, then you can safely assume that the router is the cause of the issues.  Connecting to the Internet port on the router would simply result in NO CONNECTION, not an intermittent one (in this specific case).  The problem could be the DC power adapter for the router.  It could be a defective router itself.  It could be that you don't have the wireless secured and you are getting "hit" by a neighbor (not even on purpose if you never changed the SSID).  Have you checked the router logs?

Comment: Yes, that's also what I thought. I've been looking at the router, the power seems stable. My wireless is secure. I think the router itself may be the problem, but I just enabled the logs and see what happens next. Thanks. Also, I'm stuck in this firmware since this version of WRT54G can't have a 3rd-party firmware due to its Atheros chip.

Comment: Don't forget to use a custom SSID, lock down the wireless with something... even WEP, change the wireless channel, etc.

Comment: Yes, I've done them, too. Weird, the log didn't contain anything.

Comment: I've changed cables, the used ports. Still nothing. At certain times I think at least the desktop PC loses the connection and I still don't know why. Please help.